# Arranging FPDF in Multicell?

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

I would like to make a table format on FPDF using Multicell. I would like to have a multi cell on item description, but I can't do it like this:

**|item id |code | item/Description  |unit price| total amount|**   <-this format

here is my code

```
    foreach($data as $row) { 

        $this->MultiCell($w[0],4,$row[0],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
        $this->SetFont('');

        $this->MultiCell($w[1],4,$row[1],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
        $this->SetFont('');

        $this->MultiCell($w[2],4,$row[2],'LR',0,'R',$fill);
        $this->SetFont('');

        $this->MultiCell($w[3],4,$row[3],'LR',0,'R',$fill);
        $this->SetFont('');

        $this->MultiCell($w[4],4,$row[3],'LR',0,'R',$fill);
        $this->SetFont('');

        $this->Ln();
        $fill =! $fill;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem, trying it

```
  http://youhack.me/2010/06/10/dynamically-generate-pdf-files-in-php/
```